# Strange PHP multiple file upload issue

Tags: php, file, upload

Before you asked, I did look at all the similar topics and did not not find the solution to my problem. When I try to upload multiple files, say 4, 3 files are uploaded. I am really sure the loop is correct, but i could be wrong. Self-taught PHP newbie.

The code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Upload"){
       if(count($_FILES['image_filename']['name']) == 0)
       {
            $form->seterror("fileupload"," * At least one file required.");
       }
       if($form->num_errors == 0)
       {

          $directory="../../images/properties";
          $ref='';

          //Loop through each file
          for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image_filename']['name']); $i++) 
          {

                 if($_FILES['image_filename']['name'][$i] != "")
                 {      
                    //Get the temp file path
                    $filename = $_FILES['image_filename']['name'][$i];    // filename stores the value
                    $filename = str_replace(" ","_",$filename);// Add _ inplace of blank space in file name, you can remove this line
                    $filename = stripslashes($filename); // strip file_name of slashes
                    $filename = str_replace("'","",$filename); //remove quotes
                    $filesize = $_FILES['image_filename']['size'][$i];
                    $filetype = $_FILES['image_filename']['type'][$i];
                    $filetemp = $_FILES['image_filename']['tmp_name'][$i];

                    //echo $filename.'<br>';
                    $filework->file_upload($_FILES['image_filename']['name'][$i],$directory,$_FILES['image_filename']['tmp_name'][$i]); // this is my File upload class


                    $ref=$_FILES['image_filename']['name'][$i]; 
                    if($countImg == 0) {
                       if($i==0) {
                            $main='1'; 
                       } else {
                          $main='0';
                       }
                    } else {      
                        $main='0';
                    }

                     $q="INSERT INTO property_images(property_id,image_filename,image_reference,main_image)".
                       " VALUES (".$_GET['pid'].",'".$_FILES['image_filename']['name'][$i]."','".$ref."','".$main."')";
                    //echo $q.'<br>';
                    $database->query($q) or die(mysql_error());

                    $x++;   
                 }
            }         
        }
```

}
[/code]

Comment: Could you dump/log the contents of $_FILES when you upload?

Comment: Yes, do a var_dump on $_FILES so we can see its contents

Comment: First of all, print your `$i`. Second do a `print_r($_FILES)` to be sure that every file is uploaded correctly (I mean 'at least in the `$_FILES` list) and paste the results here.

Comment: PHP.net has a page exactly for multiple files uploading - http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: This is what I get when I do

Comment: Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg [1] => Jellyfish.jpg [2] => Koala.jpg [3] => Penguins.jpg [4] => Tulips.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg [2] => image/jpeg [3] => image/jpeg [4] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\Windows\Temp\php67CD.tmp [1] => C:\Windows\Temp\php8434.tmp [2] => C:\Windows\Temp\php9998.tmp [3] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpAF3B.tmp [4] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpC4BF.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 879394 [1] => 775702 [2] => 780831 [3] => 777835 [4] => 620888 ) )

Comment: And does your $i reaches 4(do you get 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 if you print $i?)?

Comment: When I print [code] $i[/code] I get: 0-Chrysanthemum.jpg, 1-Jellyfish.jpg, 2-Koala.jpg, 3-Penguins.jpg, 4-Tulips.jpg. All files are present.

Comment: 1) Is the data available in the database(4th record)? 2) Can you post the fileupload class?

Comment: They problem may be in $filework, what library is it? Maybe it is returning some value so you can see if the upload was correct or not.

Comment: You're right, it was the file_work class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the loop skipping the last file?

Try changing this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image_filename']['name']); $i++)
```

to:

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($_FILES['image_filename']['name']); $i++)
```